# Using the modulo operator to get an infinite loop around an array

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, modulo

I'm able to come up with simple codes using the modulo operator and I understand it on an abstract level, but I'm having trouble seeing the concept/idea on the actual code.
Can anyone explain it to me using this simple version I did for an infinite loop to change the background? I would really appreciate some help. This and recursion are really giving me a hard time. I simply can't see what they do when I read the code

```
let i = 0;

function mud() {
  const doc = document.body;
  let colour = ["#5FA4FF", "#5DA3FF", "#02C2F1", "#2982F8"];
  doc.style.backgroundColor = colour[i];
  i = (i + 1) % colour.length;
}
setInterval(mud, 2000);
```

Comment: I didn't clearly understand what does mean "I understand it on an abstract level".  There is a great explanation of [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

Comment: Exactly in this code it works as infinite loop because `%  colour.length` always will give a number which less than `colour.length` and when you add `1` you just go around from `0` to `colour.length (not inclusive)`

Comment: I meant when using it for a loop.  I simply can't see the idea in the actual code: i = (i + 1) % colour.length;

Comment: Did my second comment explain to you what is meaning of modulo operator here?

Comment: It did. Thanks.

Comment: If it isn't hard for you please accept my answer. I will be grateful :)

Comment: Note that there is no recursion in this code.  `setInterval` schedules your function to run approximately every two seconds.  But the function does not call itself, directly or indirectly; that's what it would take to be recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The % is taking the remainder of division. Here's an interactive example based on your code. The variables are added to the div so you can watch their values change with the color.

```js
var mod = document.querySelector("#mod");
let i = 0;

function mud() {
    let colour = ["#5FA4FF", "#5DA3FF", "#02C2F1", "#2982F8"];
    mod.style.backgroundColor = colour[i];
    let dividend = (i + 1);
    
    //get the remainder of dividend (i+1) divided by color.length (4)
    i =  dividend % colour.length;
    mod.innerText = JSON.stringify({
        dividend,
        divisor: colour.length,
        remainder:i,
        colorHex: colour[i]
    }, null, 2);
}

setInterval(mud, 2000);
```

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="mod"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly in this code it works as infinite loop because `%  colour.length` always will give a number which less than `colour.length` and when you add `1` you just go around from `0` to `colour.length` (not inclusive)